# Replacing all characters of a given string with a specific single character python with no loops

Tags: python, string

```
str0 = input("Enter str: ")

str0 = str0.replace(str0, '_')

print(str0)
```

I need to replace each one of the characters without using loops or conditions

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think it's perfect

Comment: it's a little bit different because it's not the same solution

Answer (score 2):

```
str0 = input("Enter str: ")

str0 = '_'*len(str0)

print(str0)
```

Should work. The multiplication puts the right amount of `_`'s so that all of them are replaced.